# Easiest way to test SSH controlled device (Bitvise SSH Server)

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

So I am writing a program in C# .NET 3.5 which connects to ssh video codec device.
I know the control protocol so all commands that are going in and out.
Not having this device for testing. What's the best way to simulate it ?
I have tried with Bitvise SSH Server for Windows. I can see the messages
I send in the log. But I can't figure out how to make it send something back
to me so that I can test if my feedback processing works ok.

Comment: Maybe implement your own ssh server? For example with this library: https://github.com/Aimeast/FxSsh

Comment: trying to avoid it, it's rather difficult.

Comment: Think I have answered my own question. I have installed ubuntu on virtual box with open-ssh. Then connected my app to that server and from here can write to connected users via "write <username> [tty]" (check tty with "who" command).  Works for me !